# shorttoc: remove \part* from toc

Tags: table-of-contents, shorttoc

Hy

I'm using shorttoc package.

```
\shorttableofcontents{Sommaire}{1}
\part*{Annexes}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Annexes}
```

Annexes appear twice in the toc. How can I remove \part* from toc?

Comment: Problem resolved adding `notocpart*` to titlesec package

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because of the comment of the OP that solves the question.